# AWS assume-role equivalent in Google cloud (GCP)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform

How to setup multi-account(project) in GCP? It is possible in AWS by using `assume-role`. Anyone know how to do that in Google Cloud Platform (GCP)?

I tried exploring AWS equivalent in GCP but not able to find any documentation.

Comment: Google Cloud IAM supports accessing multiple accounts with the same credentials. The AWS AssumeRole method is not required in Google Cloud except for G Suite. Edit your question to clarify what you need to do and I will recommend how to do that. AWS and GCP are so different in how IAM is implemented that it makes no sense to compare them feature by feature.

Answer (score 7):

As documented, [AssumeRole](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html) in AWS returns a set of temporary security credentials that you can use to access AWS resources that you might not normally have access to.

In AWS you can create one set of long-term credentials in one account. Then you can use temporary security credentials to access all the other accounts by assuming roles in those accounts.

The equivalent of the above in GCP would be creating short-lived credentials for service accounts to impersonate their identities ([Documentation link](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-short-lived-service-account-credentials)).

Accordingly, in GCP you have the “caller” and the “limited-privilege service account” for whom the credential is created.

To implement this scenario, first, use handy documentation on [Service Accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) and [Cloud IAM Permission Roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles) in GCP, as each account is a Service Account with specific role permissions, in order to understand how accounts work in GCP.

The [link](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-short-lived-service-account-credentials) I posted above, provides detailed information on the [flows](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-short-lived-service-account-credentials#sa-credentials-permissions) that allow a caller to create short-lived credentials for a service account and the [supported credential types](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-short-lived-service-account-credentials#requesting_short-lived_credentials).

Additionally, [this link](https://cloud.google.com/docs/enterprise/best-practices-for-enterprise-organizations) can assist you in visualizing and understanding the resource hierarchy architecture in GCP and give you examples on how to structure your project according to your organization’s structure.

Answer (score 1):

The basic answer is "Service Roles".   Limited-time service roles are available.

For assigning permissions across projects (but still in the same organization), you can [create a custom role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-custom-roles).

For letting any user assume the role of a service account, use the [Service Account user](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#the_service_account_user_role) role.

For limited-time authorization tokens, you have [OAuth 2.0 for server-to-server calls](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount), particularly with JWT where available.

Comment: Thanks Joshua, but is it possible to manage multiple GCP projects without using access and secret key ? similar to assume-role in AWS ?

Comment: The security model is different, but custom roles in GCP let you assign permissions across projects. Does that meet your needs?  [Answer edited[.

Comment: @Janardhan please upvote and/or accept if this answer helped you.

Comment: In GCP, the Project is the trust boundary. so you probably don't want to use the same keys for multiple projects.

Comment: @TravisWebb but aren't there scenarios where cross-project access is given, e.g. Shared VPC? In general, projects are inside folders (often corresponding to a corporate department) which are inside organizations (a corporation), so doesn't it make sense to give cross-project access?

Comment: @Janardhan Note also the Service Account User role.  https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#the_service_account_user_role  Does that meet your needs?

Comment: yes thanks, without using any JSON or key file, I was able to create the instance on another project.