# Is service account impersonation in GCP the best way to handle developer credentials and permissions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

In GCP, service account impersonation is a way to create temporary IAM credentials to perform an action as developer (see [here](https://medium.com/@tanujbolisetty/gcp-impersonate-service-accounts-36eaa247f87c)). This has been described as equivalent to assuming a role in AWS - see this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58830921/aws-assume-role-equivalent-in-google-cloud-gcp).

My question is:

- is this the recommended/canonical way of doing this in google cloud, namely grouping permissions around service accounts & allowing developers to inpersonate that service account ?
- Or alternatively is it better to create custom roles and assign them directly to developers identities (and not indirectly via a service account)? But then of course you lose the advantage of short living credentials.

If the first option is valid, it would also mean that you would end up having as many service accounts as roles in AWS.

Comment: Seth Vargo's answer is correct. To add, it depends on what you are trying to accomplish and by what method. Security and Identity in Google Cloud is very different than AWS. It is best not to try to emulate one security design with another design. For users interacting with Google Cloud using the Console and Google CLI use User Credentials. For software programs use a service account. Impersonation is rarely used in Google Cloud and adds an unnecessary complication. In summary, use unique identities for authorization tailored for the tasks to be performed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *general*, you should grant IAM roles to groups, and then add developers to the appropriate groups.

For example, you may want to grant all developers "Editor" access to a project. To do this, grant `group:all-developers@yourcompany.com` the Editor role to the project. Then, use LDAP or G Suite to ensure that all developers are a member of that group.

You can give developers the ability to `actAs` a service account, but then the audit logs and principal would be the service account, not the developer.

Comment: Ok, just to understand correctly, I will assume that having long living credentials that by themselves cannot do anything, but that they can be used to get temporary credentials which can do something (assume a role in aws) is just the way AWS does it, and that GCP has a different approach (this for the use case of developers doing something, automated processes is a different story of course) .

Comment: @MarioCast - Google uses OAuth. Tokens have a lifetime of 3,600 seconds max but usually can be renewed. You are comparing two different types of authentication/authorization systems with very little implementation overlap.